# Using parent scope as a service

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have an index page with a controller scoped to `<body>`

I'm finding it very convenient to store objects on the body controller that need to be accessed by multiple views.

My question is, is there anything wrong with doing this? Traditionally, I store such objects in a service, but sometimes I just have random things that i want to persist throughout the session and i'm finding the body controller fits them quite nice. Want to make sure I understand the best practice there, why i might not do that, or why it is actually a fine idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular Documentation on [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-controller), says the following:

> Nesting controllers using ng-controller results in normal prototypal
>   inheritance, just like ng-include and ng-switch, so the same
>   techniques apply. However, "it is considered bad form for two
>   controllers to share information via $scope inheritance" --
>   http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-1-architecture/ A
>   service should be used to share data between controllers instead.

I would argue that using a service is easier to test and it is separation of concerns. Also, depending on the number of variables and their names, it will become quite confusing to keep track of the right variables. If you use a service on the other hand, some IDEs (e.g. Webstorm) will be able access the variables with auto-completion.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that in general this is a very bad practice because it goes against one of the golden principles of angularjs, which is to **keep the structure and the behavior separated**, we can do that thanks to the fact that [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) is at the core of angularjs architecture.

In general doing what you are suggesting will make your code to be more difficult to test and reuse, and in the long run more difficult to maintain too.